# Should I store temporary files in the __pycache__ folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a memoizing decorator for Python 3. The plan is to pickle the cache in a temporary file to save time across multiple executions.

The cache will be deleted if the file containing the decorated function has been changed, just like the .pyc file in __pycache__. So then I started thinking about uncluttering the user's project directory by placing the pickled cache in __pycache__. Are there side effects of storing files in this directory? Is it misleading or confusing?

Comment: I'm not understanding what your memoizing decorator actually does. Could you explain on that?

Comment: Sure! The decorator alters the function's behavior so that parameters and their results are stored in a dictionary (the cache). When the function is called, it check's whether the function has already been evaluated for those parameters. If so, the function looks up and returns the result in the dictionary rather than redoing the calculations.

Comment: Oh, great idea! It would require that the function be pure, though. However, what does `__pycache__` has to do with that? **Edit**: Now I understand; writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either...

- Have all caching to happen at runtime: This beats your purpose. However, it is the only way not to touch the filesystem at all.
- Dedicate a special folder like `__memo__` or something: This will allow you to have caching across several executions. However, you'll "pollute" the application's file structure.

Reasons you should **never** mess up with `__pycache__`:

- `__pycache__` is CPython-specific. Although it's most likely the implementation you're using right now, it's not portable/safe/good practice to assume everyone does for no good reason at all.
- `__pycache__` is intended as a transparent optimization, that is, no one should care if it exists at all or not. This is a design decision from the CPython folks, and so you should not circumvent it.
- Due to the above, the aforementioned directory may be disabled if the user wants to. For instance, in CPython, if you do `python3 -B myapp.py`, no `__pycache__` will be created if it doesn't exist, and otherwise will be ignored.
- Users often delete `__pycache__` because of the above two points for several reasons. I do, at least.
- Messing things inside `__pycache__` because "it doesn't pollute the application's file structure" is an illusion. The directory can perfectly be considered as "pollution". If the Python interpreter already pollutes stuff, why can't you with `__memo__` anyway?

Comment: Ahhh, I think an extra folder is the way to go, you're making good points. But remember that we can just create a pycache folder if it doesn't exist. So I think it's less of a portability issue so much as a potential cause of confusion: "I ran my script with -B, so why do I have a pycache folder now?!" or "Why isn't my function memoized? All I did was delete the pycache folder..."

Comment: Hm, these points are not convincing me. Most of them are in fact arguments for storing memoization in the same directory. Probably one can detect -B switch and turn of memoization then as well. We can see memoization as a form of optimization, so if user deletes `__pycache__`, maybe it is OK to restart memoization as well.